# Magento 1.9.2.4 - Activate different payment method for some customers

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, payment, payment-methods

I was looking for a Magento method for activating a different method of payment for customers who make more than three orders.

For example, if the customer makes three orders on the site normally pay with credit card. Instead, if the customer has made a quarter order is activated as payment method the money order.

It is already possible to activate this from back end of Magento or it's necessary enter in the code PHP?

Comment: You need to enter in the php code for that, to create new module. I don't think it is admin configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to use this extention : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paymentfilter-for-products-and-customer-groups.html

All you need to do is some custom code to change users group when desired business rule is met.

A lot simpler to implement as the before mentioned extension deals with the rest.

Comment: Thank you man for response. But this extention is not available for my Magento 1.9.2.4. There is a guide to do it manually? :)

Comment: See: https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter/issues/15 all in all, available via guthub. Fork ot, Clone it, test it, add a fix if needed, PR it. Contribute. The essence of opensource.

Comment: Perfect. As soon as I tried let you know. Thanks for your time to help. ;)